# How to run a jQuery Code after loading all the images in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

How to run a jQuery Code after loading all the images in my page ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

Answer (score 21):

Checking to see that all **images** have loaded is slightly involved, so unless you have a pressing need to be so precise, it is much easier to check that all image and everything else has loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

This makes use of the jQuery **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method.

If you do really need to check for specifically only images, then things get a little trickier. I initially wanted to do this:

```
$("img").load(function() { ... }); \\ THIS IS INCORRECT!!!!!
```

However the above creates a jQuery object that contains all images, and then it binds `function() { ... }` to **each** of these images. So the above will trigger a function as many times as there are images on the page!

To get around this, we should check how many images there are on the page, and only fire the function once after all those images have been loaded:

```
$(function() {  

      // To keep track of how many images have loaded
    var loaded = 0;

      // Let's retrieve how many images there are
    var numImages = $("img").length;

      // Let's bind a function to the loading of EACH image
    $("img").load(function() {

          // One more image has loaded
        ++loaded;

          // Only if ALL the images have loaded
        if (loaded === numImages) {

              // This will be executed ONCE after all images are loaded.
            function() { ... }   
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BWzUA/)**

Comment: Since he wanted it only after *all* the images on the page have been loaded, I don't think this may pose a problem.

Comment: @Daniel - Even if all the image are loaded from the browser cache (like for a previously visited page)? I'm not quite sure how the `load` is triggered in those cases.

Comment: I imagine so. There would still be other resources for the browser to load - and once they are loaded, the load event for the window will be fired. Even if every external resource is cached, I imagine it will still be fired once the page itself is done loading. I've yet to hear of the load event not firing in any valid case.

Comment: old thread, but i find this useful for checking if all images are loaded after ajax requests. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {
 var length = $('img').length ;
 var counter = 0;
 $('img').each(function() {
     $(this).load(function(){
        counter++;
        if(counter == length) {
           Callback(); //do stuff
        }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Heh, I hadn't realized what a pain this is. Though, you can remove a line by using `$("img").load()` instead of `$("img").each(function() { $(this).load() })`- See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this recently, but went about it differently.

```
$('img').on('load', function(){
    $('img').off('load'); //detaches from load event, so code below only executes once
    // my code to execute
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer. Still worth referring.

Refer

1. [Run JavaScript Only After Entire Page Has Loaded](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/run-javascript-only-after-entire-page-has-loaded/)
2. [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

**Code**

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Ajtai answer will work except on IE's cached images. To make it work with IE, here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877079 or by using the [**imagesLoaded**](http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using jquery this little snippet does the trick (it ensures that all images are loaded before any script inside it are run)...

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code goes here here
});
```