# Is there a way to get information when image is showed in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When using fullscreen image gallery and blending between pictures, some images are much bigger and takes some time to load and show up.

Yes, there is a function called `onload` which is called when image is loaded. Unfortunately, if image is really high quality, it takes some time to show up or render after load event.

My question is, how can I get know when image is rendered/showed up so I can do proper blending ?
When blending .. old image fades out, then I change an image and then I fade a new image in. Unfortunately, if image takes some time to show, it fades "nothing" in and then image will show up immediately.

Comment: Are you already waiting for `onload`? I would assume that's the best you can do.

Comment: The only option is onload, the image doesn't load faster if you use something else, the only way to make that happen is to optimize your images.

Comment: Use progressive jpegs, they work great for displaying images while downloading.

Comment: David: downloading/loading is not a problem. Problem is, it takes some time to show image up after onload function was fired.

Comment: Maybe try loading the next image while the user is viewing the current one, so the majority of the time the next image is pre-loaded when the transition is going to occur.

Comment: I just figured my problem. Actually it was not my problem, but it seems, onload is not working correctly in IE11. I tried firefox and it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
 <img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book">

 $( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

This will fire after all pictures have been loaded.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670830/2567455).

Comment: yes, that's working, unfortunately, when image is loaded, it still takes some time to SHOW UP :)